# ASP.NET Core TLS client certificate authentication only for a specific API location

Tags: asp.net-core

Is it possible in ASP.NET Core (standalone) to activate authentication with client certificates only for a specific location (API or Page)?
With IIS is it possible to define a configuration file for a folder.

```
<configuration>   
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <access sslFlags="Ssl,SslNegotiateCert,SslRequireCert" />
    </security>   
  </system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```

Can I configure the ASP.Net Core Kestrel server in a similar way?

Comment: What is the relevance of the snippet you shared? Is it from IIS? If so, how does that apply to only a specific API or page?

Comment: Anyway, if I'm reading [this Microsoft page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-5.0) right, it's not possible within the same app. ("Can I configure my app to require a certificate only on certain paths?")

Comment: Yes, this is the example for IIS configuration. I want to know how I can do that with ASP.NET Core without IIS.

Comment: The snippet you shared doesn't seem to demonstrate per-API or per-path configuration.

Comment: Thanks! I have to do SmartCard authentication when the user clicks the button "Authentication with PKI card" and then calls an API with "Client Certificate Authentication". That worked very well with IIS.I have to think about an another strategy with ASP.NET Core.

Answer (score 1):

[Steeltoe provides a client certificate auth library](https://docs.steeltoe.io/api/v3/security/mtls.html) that is based on Microsoft's client certificate authentication but allows authorization policies to be applied per-endpoint.

It was built with some additional features specific to Cloud Foundry (including pre-built authorization policies based on data inside the certificate), but you can likely ignore those pieces or build your own policies. There are some sample apps [in this repo](https://github.com/SteeltoeOSS/Samples/tree/main/Security/src) that should help demonstrate how it works